# Displaying Image in Crystal Reports 10 using C# through a File Path stored in a Database

Tags: c#, image, crystal-reports, report

I have a C# Windows Application that Stores Employee Data into a MYSQL Database including their picture's file path (\\192.168.13.6\IDPictures\Unknown.jpg).

Can someone help me on how to display the picture in a Crystal Reports 10 Report by reading the file path from the database?

I can't seem to find the answer. Please Help.

Comment: You have to use something like OLE object...

Answer (score 0):

1) Read the path.

2) Load the image: byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(path)

3) Put it into a column of type byte[] in your dataset: row[column] = buffer;

4) In Crystal, if your datasource is not the dataset, use a XSD file with a column of type base64Binary.

5) In Crystal, drag the field from the data source to the report.

Comment: I still don't get it. Forgive me. I'm new to this kind of thing. :(

How to create the XSD file? And how to set it as a data source in crystal reports?

Comment: May you tell me what is your data source in crystal reports? Are you binding directly to the data base or are you using a dataset filled in your code?

Comment: CRAXDRT.Report rpt = new CRAXDRT.Report();
            CRAXDRT.Application app = new CRAXDRT.Application();
            rpt = app.OpenReport("\\\\192.168.13.6\\Users\\Jason\\My Documents\\Visual Studio 2005\\Projects\\SPMCHRMIS_CLIENT\\Reports\\PDS.rpt", null);
            rpt.SQLQueryString = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Employee WHERE FullName = '"+fullname+"'";

Comment: the Fields PicturePath(Varchar) and Picture(Blob) are contained in the table tbl_Employee.

Comment: Try to use an OLE object. Look at this link: http://forums.asp.net/t/1933890.aspx?How+to+dynamically+add+images+in+crystal+report