# Add byte[] image to Crystal report

Tags: image, crystal-reports

How can I add the image to a report with one of the following form base 64, bitmap and byte [] ?

Answer (score 0):

I use byte[] in DataSet (C#) and base64string in XSD.

See details in other posts:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23227513/insert-image-to-crystal-reports/23243126#23243126),
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180838/displaying-image-in-crystal-reports-10-using-c-sharp-through-a-file-path-stored/27192414#27192414), or
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162526/how-to-view-dynamic-images-in-crystal-report-9-during-runtime-without-using-data/27192825#27192825)

If you are connecting directly to the database, i'm not sure how to do it.